# MS SQL returning wrong result when executed in asp

Tags: sql, select, count, group-by

I got some problems with an MS SQL statement that I use in classic ASP.. 
When I use the statement in Microsoft SQL SMS - I get the correct answer (4) but in ASP I only get the result 2..

The result I want is how many different artists have one or more published items.

The statement I use -

```
SELECT Count(*) AS CountArtists 
FROM Tekster 
WHERE Published='True' 
GROUP BY Artist
```

Data - Table(Texts)

```
Artist    -   Published  
Person1       yes  
Person1       no  
Person1       yes  
Person2       yes  
Person3       yes  
Person3       no  
Person3       yes  
Person4       no  
Person4       no  
Person4       no  
Person5       no  
Person5       yes  
Person6       no
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the connection string is the same for both queries. You are likely hitting a different database than you think you are.

Also, notice that your query is checking for `True`, but your data says `yes/no`. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you saying "published = 'true'" when the data contains "yes" and "no".

Try running the query with published = 'yes'.

Also, if you want the value 4, then you should do "count(distinct artist)" instead of count(*).

Answer (score 0):

Your original query, if you fix the `where` clause, will give you, for each artist, the count of all rows in your table where `published` is `yes|true`. You will get zero values for some presumably.

To get the results you want, and answer the question, "How many different artists have one or more published items?", you need to do something like the following:

```
select count(*)
from ( select artist
       from Tekster
       where published = 'yes'
       group by artist
       having count(*) > 1
     ) published_artist pa
```

The virtual table (subquery) gives you the set of published artists. The outer query gives you the count of published artists.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Artist) AS CountArtists FROM Tekster WHERE Published='True'

Comment: Thanks alot - that was just the right statement I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

If Published fields datatype is bit then use Published = 1